# What Equation is model.coef_ Derived From? (SKLearn)

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression, machine-learning-model

Fairly simple question, but something I've been unable to understand firmly by scouring the interwebs.
After running a LR model using SKlearn, one of the key outputs is `coef_` , along with `intercept_`.

I understand that `coef_` is a transformation matrix that fully describes the relationships of the model; and that performing the dot-product of the input data, with `coef_` and adding `intercept_` will produce the predicted values for your inputs.

**My question is**: What is the equation that defines `coef_` for a 1st-order model? How does this change with a 2nd-order model? How does this equation change with a multi-variate model that has n-features?

I've gathered that it's something along the lines of `b0 + b1x + b2x` , but I don't understand how it evolves with the introduction of additional "feature" variables and for higher-order polynomial models.

Answer (score 1):

> A linear regression line has an equation of the form $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$,
> where $x$ is the explanatory variable and $y$ is the dependent
> variable. The slope of the line is $\beta_1$ (coeff), and $\beta_0$ is the
> intercept (the value of $y$ when $x = 0$).
>
> The most common method for fitting a regression line is the method of
> least-squares. This method calculates the best-fitting line for the
> observed data by minimizing the sum of the squares of the vertical
> deviations from each data point to the line (if a point lies on the
> fitted line exactly, then its vertical deviation is 0). Because the
> deviations are first squared, then summed, there are no cancellations
> between positive and negative values.
>
> Ordinary least squares (OLS) is the most common estimator. OLS
> estimates are commonly used to analyze both experimental and
> observational data. The OLS method minimizes the sum of squared
> residuals, and leads to a closed-form expression for the estimated
> value of the unknown parameter vector $β$:
> $\hat {\boldsymbol {\beta }}=(\mathbf {X} ^{\mathsf {T}}\mathbf {X} )^{-1}\mathbf {X} ^{\mathsf {T}}\mathbf {Y}$ where $Y$ is a vector
> whose ith element is the ith observation of the dependent variable,
> and $X$ is a matrix whose ij element is the ith observation of the jth
> independent variable.

**NOTE** Higher-order polynomial regression can be treated as an extension to linear regression by treating $x^2$, $x^3$, .. as extra features and using linear least squares with previous formula. That is one uses linear least squares on $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2 + ..$ where $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$, .. are assumed as different features.

> In statistics, polynomial regression is a form of regression analysis
> in which the relationship between the independent variable x and the
> dependent variable y is modelled as an nth degree polynomial in x.
> Polynomial regression fits a nonlinear relationship between the value
> of x and the corresponding conditional mean of y, denoted E(y |x).
> Although polynomial regression fits a nonlinear model to the data, as
> a statistical estimation problem it is linear, in the sense that the
> regression function E(y | x) is linear in the unknown parameters that
> are estimated from the data. For this reason, polynomial regression is
> considered to be a special case of multiple linear regression.

References:

1. http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/linreg.htm
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression

Comment: Thanks for the excerpt and the breakdown @Nikos M.

Comment: Then, by extension, for a multi-variate, polynomial equation would it look like the following? 
y= a + (b*x1) + (c*x2) + (d*x1^2) + (e*x2^2)...  where a, b, c,... are the coefficients, and x1 and x2 are the different features

Comment: yes that is correct exactly

Comment: I also understand that with this formula structure, there are feature-to-feature interactions that also come into play. For example: ending up with terms such as `(b*x1*c*x2)`. Is that correct? And if so, how does the initial equation get transformed into a function with these inter-variable relationship terms?

Comment: One can add interactions to the mixture if one wants to, but is not necessary

Comment: Then $x_1 x_2$ for example is treated as new independent feature (like $x_1^2$)

Comment: Is that dependent on the model type that is selected? I'm evaluating with a polynomial linear regression model (2nd order), but am interested in characterizing these inter-feature relationships

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are after.